# Access custom cell in ViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to access the alpha value of a label in a custom cell when the user scroll the table view.

My custom cell class:

```
class HeaderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var monigerTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var monigerSubtitle: UILabel!

    func setAlpha(to alpha: CGFloat) {
        buttonOutlet.alpha = alpha
        monigerTitle.alpha = alpha
        buttonOutlet.alpha = alpha
    }
}
```

The function called on scroll :

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    guard let cell = itemsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell") as? HeaderTableViewCell else {
        return
    }
    cell.setAlpha(to: 1 - scrollView.contentOffset.y / 30)
    print(cell.monigerTitle.alpha)
}
```

The print statement prints the correct alpha values but don't affect the storyboard when I launch the app.

I tried to replace :

```
itemsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell")
```

by :

```
itemsTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
```

But it don't pass through the guard statement.

**Edit (new attempt):**

```
for cell in itemsTableView.visibleCells {
    if let headerCell = cell as? HeaderTableViewCell {
        print("success")
        headerCell.setAlpha(to: 1 - scrollView.contentOffset.y / 30)
    }
}
```

Then I tried to print the reuseIdentifier for all visible cells and this is the result :

> nil Optional("itemCell") Optional("itemCell") Optional("itemCell")
>   Optional("itemCell") Optional("itemCell")

The first one is nil, but it should be "headerCell", it's correctly set in the interface builder.

My tableView with both header cells and item cells :

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need

```
guard let cells = itemsTableView.visibleCells as? [HeaderTableViewCell] else { return }
```

`cellForRowAt` runs when the item is visible and you always pass index 0

**Edit:**

```
itemsTableView.visibleCells.forEach {

    if let cell = $0 as? CellName1 {
    }
    else if let cell = $0 as? CellName2 { 
    }
}
```

Comment: It fails the Guard statement too

Comment: sure table cells are of type `HeaderTableViewCell ` ?? not header cell ?

Comment: Maybe it's because I have others kind of cells too, let me try something, I'll let you know if it works

Comment: yes , this may be a reason as the cast will fail for different types

Comment: No, I didn't solved it, I edit the post with my new attempt

Comment: @Placard you need to access the header cell not main cells , Do you regsieter `headerCell` for table header or main cells ??

Comment: I think it's a main cell, but not sure to understand the question sorry..

Comment: can you show how you register the table with those identifiers ??

Comment: Yes no problem !

Comment: where you assign values for the header cell ?

Comment: Ok I solved the problem, It was a stupid mistake, your first answer actually works, do I check your answer or do I post my own answer which is pretty ridiculous ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your last comment, I don't have a very good English.. ^^

Comment: @Placard if the answer solved the problem check it , if not and your attempt is different then post it